# Remove backdrop-filter then entire component's background disappear

Tags: css, sass, frontend, backdrop

I am a intern working on a company's project, what I wanted to do is to remove the blur effect on the modal.

Original scss:

```
@mixin card {
    background: $color-surface($background, 0.5);;
    backdrop-filter: blur(28px) !important;
    border-radius: $card-border-radius;
}
```

Original display

[image]

Changed scss:

```
@mixin card {
    background: rgba($color-surface, 0.5);
    border-radius: $card-border-radius;
}
```

Changed Display:

[image]

Which both the text and the background is disappeared, my guess is the "white" background is covering the text and the $color-surface light blue background, but I wonder why is that ?

How can I remove the blur effect properly ?

Thanks for any comments or answers.

Comment: The reason why you need to post a [reprex] is that we don't have to guess with you. We need to see how it is used and what the processed code looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into how to produce a minimal reproducible example